# TF corrupted record while training

Tags: tensorflow

I was training a neural network overnight and it crashed. I have 2 questions:

1. What causes this error?
2. How can I prevent it from happening again?

The 2 main errors are:

1. ERROR:tensorflow:Exception in QueueRunner: corrupted record at 52284962154
2. DataLossError (see above for traceback): corrupted record at 52284962154

**EDIT**

The same code was used on another machine and it crashed with the same error after about 6 hours. The number 52284962154 was identical.

Comment: It certainly sounds like a bug. Could you [open an issue on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new)? It would be very helpful if you could boil things down to a minimal reproduction you could include with the bug report, but a full trace would help regardless.

Comment: Ran it overnight again, got the same error at the same number. 52284962154. I'll file an issue.

Comment: @AllenLavoie, the error is reproducible. We have 13 million 33x33x3 patches and run it in batches of 256. It will bug out at step 30747. I suspect it's a corrupted TFRecord during write. What's the best thing to do now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was a write error. After converting the data to TFRecords again, the error disappeared. It can go beyond step 30747 now.

Comment: When you mean write error? What are you implying? Did you just have to run this same script again when training?